# Custom text in header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using fancyhdr and want to have custom text in the header which changes every few pages. Currently I am using the trick with `markboth` - I have a function `\newcommand{\setheaderdata}[2]{\markboth{#1}{#2}}` and then display these data with 
`\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{\
    \fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{\rightmark}
}`
The trouble is, now I want to add a third text to the header and since there is no `centermark`, I have no way of getting it into the header.

I have tried making a custom command which I redefine every time I want to change the header text, but for some reason, the headers ignore this redefinition...

So, how do I get custom text (which changes throughout the document) into the header?

Comment: How would it change?  According to which rules?

Comment: It would change every time `setheaderdata` is called. It can be any text.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example code with some of these header data? I'm not sure I fully understand, but Id think it might be easier with `titleps`.

Comment: the `mark`s are to be set by chapter and section headings. If you want to put *any* text you want to the headers and footers, do: `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Wombat}\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Capybara}\fancyhead[CE]{Mara}\fancyhead[CO]{Mlha}`

Comment: The problem is, I don't know whether i want to put `Wombat` or `Capybara` in the heading, because the contents of the document are generated with a Lua script

Comment: So your Lua script can place Wombat and Capybara (or whatever the real content is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, I couldn't find any solution using the `fancyhdr` package and as far as I know, pagestyles cannot be renewed. But (thanks to Bernard) I found a solution using the `titleps` package:

```
\newcommand{\headerdatafirst}{}
\newcommand{\headerdatasecond}{}
\newcommand{\headerdatathird}{}

\newshortmark\headerdatafirst
\newshortmark\headerdatasecond
\newshortmark\headerdatathird

\newpagestyle{datastyle}{
    \sethead{\headerdatafirst}{\headerdatasecond}{\headerdatathird}
}

\newcommand{\setheaderdata}[3]{
    \renewcommand{\headerdatafirst}{#1}
    \preshortmark\headerdatafirst
    \renewcommand{\headerdatasecond}{#2}
    \preshortmark\headerdatasecond
    \renewcommand{\headerdatathird}{#3}
    \preshortmark\headerdatathird
}
```

Now every time `setheaderdata` is called, the pagestyle `datastyle` will contain the parameters in the header (until `setheaderdata` is called again).